# System.Text.Json conditionally ignore property on runtime

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I wonder, if there is a way to ignore property on runtime.

for example, i have class like this

```
public class FooBar
{
   public string Foo { get; set; }
   public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I want to conditionally ignore property `Bar` on runtime. so the property not be serialized in my json.

I'm using NET 5.0 right now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What **exactly** does the word "conditionally" imply in this question? Do you want to serialize it, or not, based on some condition? Or do you perhaps want to **un**conditionally ignore it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i want to serialize it based on some condition

Comment: @JohnSari Then you can create an anonymous object (option 1) in my answer. Check for the condition. If satisfied, then create anonymous object. `If (condition) { anonymous object with custom properties } else { serialize C# object will all properties }`.

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny It's a brilliant Idea. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use custom json converter:

```
public class FooBarConverter : JsonConverter<FooBar>
{
    public override FooBar Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var fooBar = new FooBar();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.EndObject)
            {
                return fooBar;
            }

            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
            {
                var propertyName = reader.GetString();
                reader.Read();
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case nameof(FooBar.Bar):
                        var bar = reader.GetString();
                        fooBar.Bar = bar;
                        break;
                    case nameof(FooBar.Foo):
                        var foo = reader.GetString();
                        fooBar.Foo = foo;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        throw new JsonException();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, FooBar value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();

        writer.WriteString(nameof(FooBar.Bar), value.Bar);
        // your condition
        writer.WriteString(nameof(FooBar.Foo), value.Foo);

        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

How to use the custom converter.

```
var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new FooBarConverter() }
};

var fooBar = new FooBar { Bar = "bar", Foo = "foo" };
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(fooBar, serializerOptions);
var deserializedFooBar = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FooBar>(json, serializerOptions);
```

In `Write` method you can specify your condition and based on the condition you can call `write.WriteString`.

If the condition is based on the value of another object then you can pass the object before serialization/deserialization. I think that it can be disadvantages in some cases.

Comment: msdn:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#register-a-custom-converter

Comment: @FLYFLU the usage is simplified because the whole context is not known.

Comment: So, I still need to manually iterate through all properties in `.Write` manually

Answer (score -2):

You have a couple of options available :

**Option 1** : You can instead create anonymous objects in C# :

```
FooBar obj = new FooBar();
var anon = new {
    Foo = obj.Foo;
};
```

**Option 2** :You can use `JsonIgnore` :

```
public class FooBar
{
   public string Foo { get; set; }
   [JsonIgnore]
   public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

In general, the first option will give you more flexibility. In you specific case, since you conditionally want to ignore the properties, option 1 will be the one to go for. You can write your condition as :

```
If (condition)
{
   var anon = new
   {
      Foo = obj.Foo;
   };
}
else
{
    var notAnon = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);  //Serialize with all the properties in it
    //OR do something else
}
```